# Wicket - can you specify markups IDs for elements inside repeaters?

Tags: wicket

I'm having a hard time testing our Wicket application using Selenium because of the random markup ids.

For individual elements, I can use `abc.setOutputMarkupId(true).setMarkupId("myId")`
to set their markup id explicitly.
But what if the element is added dynamically using a repeater (like ListView)? Is there a way to specify how the markup id sequence should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, can't you do the same thing with ListView? If you make your own `ListView` implementation, and then in the `populateItem(final ListItem<?> listItem)` method, on that respective `listItem` you do:

```
listItem.setOutputMarkupId(true); // write id attribute of element to html
listItem.setMarkupId("id"+i);
```

where `i` is some index you initialize in the ListView's constructor or something?

Comment: ListItem has method #getIndex()

Answer (score 1):

as Andrei told that its possible but dangerous.
setMarkupId doc:

> > Retrieves id by which this component is represented within the markup. This is either the id attribute set explicitly via a call to
> >     org.apache.wicket.Component.setMarkupId(java.lang.String), id
> >     attribute defined in the markup, or an automatically generated id - in
> >     that order. If no explicit id is set this function will generate an id
> >     value that will be unique in the page. This is the preferred way as
> >     there is no chance of id collision.
> >     http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.0/p/org.apache.wicket/c/Component#top

and also you cant get the markup id with getMarkupId()

Comment: That's a good point, however I think that creating somekind of global (or even idividual per element type) sequencer (using AtomicInteger for instance) could take care of the uniqueness of the id. The issue with the Wicket generated one is that it changes each time the app/page are reloaded, which makes it a nightmare for automated functional testing.